# Ruby Mongo mapper contains "abc"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb

Instead of saying:

```
@b = coll.find("xpto.it" => @email)
```

if it's equal to `@email`, how can I look if it contains the string `@email`?

**EDIT**

It doesn't work when there's something like:

```
"Donald Trump <donal@tr.com>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also construct a regular expression dynamically. To match a given search string:

```
search_string = @email

# Constructor syntax
coll.find({"name" => Regexp.new(search_string)})

# Literal syntax
coll.find({"name" => /#{search_string}/})
```

Reference:

http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/current/file.TUTORIAL.html

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. IT does not returns anything when the string is inside < >